# Как группировать репозитории по папкам на github или ...?

Tags: git, github, репозиторий

Допустим в моём аккаунте на github есть 100 репозиториев.

Могу ли я на github сгруппировать по папкам/категориям имеющиеся у меня репозитории? Можно ли такое сделать на других сервисах, типо bitbucket или gitlab?

Comment: в bitbucket есть projects

Answer (score 4):

В `github` для этого можно создавать, так называемые, `organization`. Но у них невозможно создавать подгруппы. В `gitlab` для этого можно создавать `group`. В отличие от `github` здесь можно создавать подгруппы `subgroup`.

Comment: А вы не знаете, есть ли возможность создать эту "организацию" без указания реквизитов банковской карты?

Comment: Сейчас перепроверил. Я смог создать организацию и при этом не указывал реквизиты для оплаты. И я выбирал бесплатный план.